# Sending all workers message after receiving message from a single worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

I am trying to have my master distribute work among the workers and the only thing it does is send out messages to all of the workers once it has received a message from one of the workers.

I have tried including worker.send inside of the worker.on function as you can see below. For some reason, it will print each workers own id 'text to' followed by its same id, but is not printing off any other combinations. (ex. '0 text to 3')

```
const cluster = require('cluster')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        const worker = cluster.fork({id: i})
        worker.on('message', text => {
            worker.send(text)
        })
    }
}
else {
    const id = Number(process.env.id)
    let messagesReceived = 0
    process.send(id)
    process.on('message', text => {
        console.log(text, 'text to', id)
        messagesReceived++
    })
    if (messagesReceived >= numCPUs) process.exit()
}
```

Essentially in the example, I want each worker to be able to send their own id to the master, and for master to send the message to all of the workers. Each worker should print every combination of number 'text to' number. Numbers going up to how many workers there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your master process is only sending a message back to a worker once it has sent its initial message to the master. If you're wanting to *broadcast* a message to all workers, then you'll need to maintain an array of workers and send to them all in a loop.

```js
const cluster = require('cluster')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    masterLogic();
} else {
    workerLogic();
}

async function masterLogic() {
    const workers = await Promise.all(
      [...Array(numCPUs).keys()].map(i => spawnWorker(i));
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        workers.forEach(worker => worker.send(`Message #${i}`));
    }  
}

function spawnWorker(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const worker = cluster.fork({ id: i })
        worker.on('message', text => {
           resolve(worker); 
        });
    });
}

function workerLogic() {
    const id = Number(process.env.id)
    let messagesReceived = 0
    process.send(id)
    process.on('message', text => {
        console.log(text, 'text to', id)
        messagesReceived++
    })
    if (messagesReceived >= numCPUs) process.exit()  
}
```